# Why wstring can accept WCHAR[] while string doesn't accept UCHAR[]

Tags: c++

I am trying to print the returned value of `NtQueryValueKey` which is `UCHAR Data[1];` i have tried `printf`, `cout`, and `string(Data, DataLengh)`, with the first two printing only 1 character and the last one throws an exception... Basically if i changed the Data Type to `WCHAR Data[1]` and used `wstring(Data)` it accepts it normally without any complain... also `wprintf` prints the value normally.

Edit: I meant `NtQueryValueKey` using the `KEY_VALUE_PARTIAL_INFORMATION`, I am using VS 2015 btw...

Comment: 1. give code 2. what compiler / IDE do You use?

Comment: It is a native OS api function, it *always* produces Unicode strings.  And has done so for the past 23 years.  If you want to turn the clock back to the 1980s then you must use the winapi function, RegQueryValueExA().

Answer (score 1):

You must have mixed something up. You did not specify what value from the `KEY_NAME_INFORMATION` enumeration you are using for the second parameter to specify the data type, but a quick look at MSDN shows that all of the structures contain `WCHAR Name[1];` or something similar as the last member (which I guess is the one you are interested in). Can you elaborate and provide the link or other means of documentation that states you actually need to use `UCHAR` ?

Comment: None of the `KEY_INFORMATION_CLASS` structures have `Data` or `DataLength` fields.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

[`WCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#WCHAR) is an alias for `wchar_t`. `std::wstring` operates with `wchar_t` elements. A `WCHAR[]` can decay to a `wchar_t*`, and thus can be assigned directly to a `std::wstring`.

[`UCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#UCHAR) is an alias for `unsigned char`. `std::string` operates with `char` elements instead.  A `UCHAR[]`/`UCHAR*` cannot be assigned directly to a `std::string` without a type-cast to `char*`, as `char` and `unsigned char` are distinct data types.

`unsigned char` is commonly used to represent 8bit bytes (it is the same data type used for [`BYTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#BYTE)).

`NtQueryKey()` returns strings as UTF-16LE encoded bytes using `WCHAR[]` character arrays, not `UCHAR[]` byte arrays.  So your code is declaring things wrong if you are using `UCHAR[]` to begin with.  But even so, you *can* use `UCHAR` if you pay attention to the encoding and byte length, and use appropriate type-casts.

Any associated `Length` value reported by `NtQueryKey()` is expressed in bytes, not characters. `sizeof(UCHAR)` is 1 and `sizeof(WCHAR)` is 2.  So every 2 `UCHAR`s represents 1 `WCHAR`.  And the strings are not null-terminated, so you have to take the `Length` into account when printing or converting.

In Latin-based languages, most commonly used Unicode characters will be <= U+00FF, and thus every other `UCHAR` in UTF-16LE will usually be 0. That is interpreted as a null terminator when UTF-16 is printed with `printf()` or `std::cout`. You need to use `wprintf()` or `std::wcout` instead.

Converting `Data` to a `std::string` is a valid operation and should not be raising an exception:

```
std::string((char*)Data, DataLength)
```

Provided that:

- `Data` is a valid pointer.
- `DataLength` is an accurate byte count.

The only way this could raise an exception is if either:

- `Data` is not pointing at valid memory.
- the value of `DataLength` is more than the actual number of bytes allocated for `Data`.
- available memory is too low to allocate `std::string`'s internal buffer.
- memory is corrupted.

Assigning `Data` by itself to a `std::wstring` without taking `DataLength` into account is not a valid operation because the strings are not null-terminated. You must specify the length:

```
std::wstring(Data, DataLength / sizeof(WCHAR))
```

If `Data` is `UCHAR` then use a type-cast:

```
std::wstring((WCHAR*)Data, DataLength / sizeof(WCHAR))
```

When printing `Data` directly with `wprintf()`, you must pass `DataLength` as an input parameter:

```
wprintf(L"%.*s", DataLength / sizeof(WCHAR), Data);
```

When printing `Data` directly with `std::wcout`, you should use `write()` instead of `operator<<` so you can pass `DataLength` as an input parameter:

```
std::wcout.write(Data, DataLength / sizeof(WCHAR));
```

If `Data` is `UCHAR` then use a type-cast:

```
std::wcout.write((WCHAR*)Data, DataLength / sizeof(WCHAR));
```